# Traefik middleware does not work for minikubeminikube traefik middleware

Tags: minikube, traefik, traefik-middleware

Everything seems normal，but the middleware does not add a header to the request.
I don't know where the problem is.If you need additional information, please let me know.
Thank you very much for your help！

```
~$ kubectl get ingressclass -n test
NAME      CONTROLLER                      PARAMETERS   AGE
traefik   traefik.io/ingress-controller   <none>       4d
```

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gsp
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service.passhostheader: "true"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: test-fix-header@kubernetescrd
spec:
  rules:
  - host: minikube.gsp.devops
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /domain
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: gsp-domain
            port:
              number: 8084
```

```
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: fix-header
  namespace: test
spec:
  headers:
    customRequestHeaders:
      X-Gsp-Ua: "browser"
```

[traefik dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs5hn.png)

Version：

- k8s v1.23.8
- traefik v2.1

I tried to add `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik`  ,but 404 will appear when accessing / domain

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gsp
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    #kuberneteskubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service.passhostheader: "true"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: test-fix-header@kubernetescrd
```